# Can you use the Big Theorem to compute limits of rational functions at infinity?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The Big Theorem is used for sequences and natural numbers, but can we still apply it to continuous functions?

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be sequences. $a_n \ll b_n \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$

The Big Theorem:  $\ln n \ll n^a \ll c^n \ll n! \ll n^n, \forall a > 0, \forall c > 1$

It establishes a hierarchy among positive sequences.

Essentially, it's saying that the denominator approaches infinity faster than the numerator, even though both eventually approach infinity.

Now, let's say I wanted to compute this limit: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x}$$

Applying the Big Theorem to a similar problem, but with natural numbers, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{e^n} = 0$$, for some natural number n.

I'm thinking that even though sequences only use natural numbers, they still approach the same number at infinity as its continuous counterpart. Is my assumption wrong? Are there any questions that would give the wrong answer if we used the Big Theorem instead of L'Hopital's law?

Note: There are some functions that can be defined such that the sequence of natural numbers of that function has a limit, but the continuous function doesn't have a limit (for example, let $f(x)$ be a sin function s.t. it has x-intercepts at 1, 2, 3, 4, ... . Let $a_n = f(n)$. Now, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$, but $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = DNE$). I'll adjust my question 'not to include such examples', if that makes sense, because questions that ask to compute limits don't necessarily define such functions. My main question is with regards to simple functions, such as $\ln n, n^a, c^n, n!, n^n$.

Comment: I don't know the big theorem, but another way (equivalent to the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition) to define limits of functions is by sequences. If the limit as $x\rightarrow +\infty$ exists, then the limit for every sequence (in the domain of the function) that positively diverges is the same number, in particular for $a_n=n \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: What does $a_n < < b_n$ mean? How is it defined? I ask because, if I had to guess at the definition of $a_n < < b_n$ from my own mathematical experience, then I would say it is defined to mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$. Which, of course, makes *The Big Theorem* entirely trivial and hence entirely useless.

Comment: @LeeMosher The Big Theorem establishes a hierarchy amongst those positive sequences. I changed the post to make it clear what the theorem itself is. My mistake. Your definition of $a_n << b_n$ (which can be read as "$a_n$ is much smaller than $b_n$") is correct. That notation is used in the Big Theorem, so I defined it in the second line. The theorem is used to compute rational sequences quickly, where you just have to find the 'largest' sequence in the numerator and denominator to know if the rational sequence goes to 0, infinity, or a number.

Comment: "$a_n$ is much smaller than $b_n$" is not a definition. Use `\ll` to bring out the $\ll$

Comment: @FShrike Yes, it isn't. The definition is written in the question. "$a_n$ is much smaller than $b_n$" is the equivalent way of saying it in English, during a conversation.

Comment: It's not always true that the limit of something along an integer sequence exists --> the limit over all real numbers exists. Consider $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(2\pi x)$ does not exist yet $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(2\pi n)$ *does*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extend in many cases this kind of results obtained for sequences also for continuous functions as follows using that $\forall x\in \mathbb R\;\exists n\in \mathbb Z$ such that $x\in [n,n+1)$. Notably, for the given example we have

$$ \frac{n}{e^{n+1}}\le \frac{x}{e^x} \le \frac{n+1}{e^n}$$

and then conclude by squeeze theorem.

As already noted in the comments, this is not possible in general (e.g. $a_n=\sin(2\pi n)$).

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that any proof of your "Big Theorem" could easily be adapted to prove a suitable continuous version, e.g.
$$\forall a > 0, \forall c > 1,\ln x \ll x^a \ll c^x \ll \lfloor x\rfloor! \ll x^x$$
where $f(x)\ll g(x)$ means $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.